# How do I make a keyboard cable detachable with a USB C female port?

Tags: wiring, usb-device, usb-c, keyboard

Alright so I'm new to all of this but I've been modding my keyboard recently and would like to get a custom cable for it.

I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKnwRu46rQg) video on how to do this with a USB micro connector, however I know that it will be a bit different for type C.

Also, I know that video isn't that good considering that person didn't even know to shrink the heatshrink. I'm thinking of doing this method, but with solder heatshrinks such as [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07C3MKM3K).

Any pointers on how I should go about doing all of this? Alternatively, would it work if I just did it how they did in that video, then used an adapter such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VBV1PY5)? Thanks!

Note: I do not have a soldering iron.

Comment: Technically it is out of the "rules" (vs functional) part of the spec for a low speed device to have a detachable cable, but that won't matter for personal use, if you want to do it anyway, look up usual device side wiring.

Comment: Like this ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pb3fpSmOrc4

Comment: anything you can send that is a bit more specific @ChrisStratton?

Comment: @MatsKarlsson that requires soldering, I don't have a soldering iron.

Comment: You're unlikely to get anywhere without a willingness to solder.  But this project seemed inadvisable from the start, probably best to just leave the cable stock and working.