# Any teardowns of a usb type a male to type c female adapter?

Tags: usb-device, adapter, usb-c, keyboard, usb-host

I'm trying to make my keyboard cable detachable and USB type C, need to know how the wires in a type a male to type c female adapter would look (one with a short wire in between and not just a board).

Comment: This is little more than a rephrasing of your existing question of earlier today. [How do I make a keyboard cable detachable with a USB C female port?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/527246/how-do-i-make-a-keyboard-cable-detachable-with-a-usb-c-female-port)  do not re-post, rather edit your existing question.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the official spec on how to go from A to C:

[image]